# Xcode - obtaining a list of all method headers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a .m file like this:

```
- (void) myMethod1 {
  // bla bla
}


- (int) rotate:(int)value {
  // bla bla
}


- (myClass *) processObject:(myClass *)object {
  // bla bla
}
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
- (void) myMethod1;
- (int) rotate:(int)value;
- (myClass *) processObject:(myClass *)object;
```

or in other words, to extract from the .m all the method headers.

Is that possible to do that in Xcode/OSX? Thanks

Comment: You mean in the runtime?  Or with a script?

Comment: @borrrden the runtime won't very useful, due to the manner in which types decay. it will of course be abi compatible, but practically useless in most cases (beyond code generators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to see the [Objective-c RunTime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) for doing this kind of jobs. This is an Example [Project](http://x-cake.ning.com/profiles/blogs/browsing-the-objc-runtime-on?xg_source=activity) for getting this.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comments, the objc-runtime approach won't be very useful for human-facing declarations (although it could be useful if the result is machine-facing/codegen).

another option would be to write a quick script/program to generate these declarations from a .m file -- just a quick string parser. if your written style is consistent, it won't take very long to write.